# Message is not shown on ajax update

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I've read dozens of question regarding similar problem, but could not find an answer to it. I've got this piece of code inside a form:

```
<p:outputPanel id="articleInfo">
    <p:growl id="messages" autoUpdate="true"/>
    <p:panel rendered="#{not empty myBB.selectedProduct}">
        <p:panel>
            <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{myBB.content}"/>
        </p:panel>
        <p:commandButton value="Button" update=":mainForm:articleInfo"/>    
    </p:panel>
</p:panel>
```

When I click a button, new content is generated in the backing bean and `FacesMessage` is added like this:

```
public String getContent(){
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(severity, title, detail));
    return "something";
}
```

The ajax update is fine because I see new content, `addMessage` is also called, but I cannot see the message. I've tried `p:messages` instead of growl, adding `for="mainForm:articleInfo"` and calling the `addMessage` with "mainForm:articleInfo" (I've checked that it's the correct ID in the view.

I still cannot find a reason for this.

Comment: p:commandButton has update property itself why are you using ajax event.

Comment: It's actually copied from the ```p:tree```, but I wanted to keep the code minimal. if I put it straight on the commandButton update attribute, the outcome is the same. I've changed it so it's not that confusing.

Comment: I don't see actionListener or action on cmomand button ??

Comment: There is none. Why do I need it? The update works fine and the content is reloaded.

Comment: ok this is confusing...who is adding message to the faces context? What actino is doing that ? If possioble, post full cod.e

Comment: The message is added in the getter when ```#{myBB.content}``` is loaded. I've updated the question.

Comment: This is not ideal. You should not add such things in a getter as it gets called more than ones. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times

Comment: Ideally, yo'd add such a message on some action.

Comment: Try to update the `p:panel` only or just the `h:outputText` or put the growl at the end of the panel. I guess the reason that you do not see any message, is that the `h:outputText` is rendered after the `p:growl/messages` when you are updating the `p:outputPanel`. So the messages is added after the update of the message container is complete.

Comment: I've refactored the code so that the message is added on action and not from the getter and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Makky: Could you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your `messages` are not displayed `because` you've added the code to add message in a `getter` which is not `ideal`.
[Why getter gets called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/)

Remove the adding message code and put inside a `method` which gets called on some `action`.